# Prove the general inclusion-exclusion rule via mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> "For any finite set A, N(A) denotes the number of elements in A."
>
> Theorem 9.3.3 The Inclusion/Exclusion Rule for Two or Three Sets
>   If A, B, and C are any finite sets, then
>   $N(A ∪ B) = N(A) + N(B) − N(A ∩ B)$ and $N(A ∪ B ∪ C) = N(A) + N(B) + N(C) − N(A ∩ B) − N(A ∩ C) −N(B ∩ C) + N(A ∩ B ∩ C)$.
>
> "It can be shown using mathematical induction (see exercise 48 at the end of this section) that formulas analogous to those of Theorem 9.3.3 hold for unions of any finite number of sets."

[image]

Source: Discrete Mathematics with Applications Susanna S. Epp

My attempt(edited)

For all natural numbers n, let the P(n) be the following property:
$N(A_1 ∪ A_2 ∪ \cdots ∪ A_n)$
$= ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 ≤ n} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 < a_2 ≤ n} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) + ∑ \limits_{1≤ {a_1} < {a_2} < n} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_n) - \cdots + (-1)^n N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_n)$

**Show that P(1) is true**

As for P(1)
$N(A_1)= N(A_1)$ by The Addition Rule ......a

By the way, $∑ \limits_{1≤ i <j ≤ 1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) = 0$ since $A_{a_2}=Ø$
So $N(A_1) = ∑ \limits_{1≤ i ≤ 1} N(A_{a_1})=N(A_1)$....b
By a, b, P(1) is true

**Show that for all integers $l$ with 1≤l≤m, $\space if \space p(l) \space \text{is true, then}\space p(m+1)$ is true.**

Inductive hypothesis is $N(A_1 ∪ A_2 ∪ \cdots ∪ A_l)$
$\space\space\space  = ∑ \limits_{1 ≤ a_1 ≤ l} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑ \limits_{1≤{a_1}<{a_2}≤l} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) +  ∑ \limits_{1≤ {a_1} <{a_2}< {a_3} ≤ l} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_{a_3}) - \cdots + (-1)^{l+1} N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_l)$
as an inductive hypothesis.

Then we must show the following p(m+1) is true.

$N(A_1 ∪ A_2 ∪ \cdots ∪ A_m ∪ A_{m+1})$
$\space\space\space  = ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 ≤ m+1} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 < a_2 ≤ m+1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) + ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 < a_2 < a_3 ≤m+1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_{a_3}) - \cdots +(-1)^{m+1}∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 <a_2<...<a_m ≤ m+1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ \cdots ∩ A_{a_m}) + (-1)^{m+2} N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_m ∩ A_{m+1})$

since $1≤m≤m$, p(m) is true by inductive hypothesis.

N($A_1 ∪ A_2∪\cdots ∪ A_m$) =
$∑ \limits_{1 ≤ i ≤ m} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑\limits_{1≤a_1<a_2≤m} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) 
+  ∑\limits_{1≤{a_1}<{a_2}<{a_3}≤m} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_{a_3})  
 - \cdots + (-1)^{m+1}N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_m)$

Let B=$A_1 ∪ A_2∪\cdots ∪ A_m$, then the LHS of p(m+1) is $N(B∪A_{m+1})$

Hence $N(B∪A_{m+1}) = N(B)+N(A_{m+1})-N(B∩A_{m+1})$
= $∑ \limits_{1 ≤ {a_1} ≤ m} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑\limits_{1≤a_1<a_2≤m} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) 
+  ∑\limits_{1≤{a_1}<{a_2}<{a_3}≤m} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_{a_3})  
 - \cdots + (-1)^{m+1}N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_m) +N(A_{m+1}) -N((A_1 ∪ A_2∪\cdots ∪A_m)∩A_{m+1})) $
  by inductive hypothesis.

Now, in order to prove p(m+1), we should show the last formula driven by the inductive hypothesis  equal to RHS of p(m+1). Right?

Then how can we show

$∑ \limits_{1 ≤ {a_1} ≤ m} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑\limits_{1≤a_1<a_2≤m} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) 
+  ∑\limits_{1≤{a_1}<{a_2}<{a_3}≤m} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_{a_3})  
 - \cdots + (-1)^{m+1}N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_m) +N(A_{m+1}) -N((A_1 ∪ A_2∪\cdots ∪A_m)∩A_{m+1})) $

is equal to the following?

$∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 ≤ m+1} N(A_{a_1}) - ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 < a_2 ≤ m+1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2}) + ∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 < a_2 < a_3 ≤m+1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ A_{a_3}) - \cdots +(-1)^{m+1}∑ \limits_{1≤ a_1 <a_2<...<a_m ≤ m+1} N(A_{a_1} ∩ A_{a_2} ∩ \cdots ∩ A_{a_m}) + (-1)^{m+2} N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_m ∩ A_{m+1})$

Comment: In your statements, you've written union symbols $\cup$ where you want intersection symbols $\cap$. That could be part of your confusion.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I edited the part.

Comment: You've done a partial edit. There should be **no** union symbols on the right hand side of any of those equations.

Comment: You are wrong in proving $P(1)$. E.g.$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq1}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\right)=0$ because the
summation is empty. There are no tuples $\langle i,j\rangle\in\mathbb{N}$
with $1\leq i<j\leq1$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I completed the edit.

Comment: @drhab Then Isn't $\sum\limits_{1\le i< j \le 1} N(A_i \bigcup A_j) = N(A_1)$?

Comment: No, it is not. All sums are empy (hence take value $0$) *except* the first wich takes value $N(A_1)$. Fortunately that makes things easyer. It becomes evident that LHS$=$RHS.

Comment: Yikes! You should not have changed the symbols on the left side of the equation! On the left you should have $\cup$, on the right you should have $\cap$. Look at your book again. You will not be able to complete the exercise until you, *very slowly and carefully*, understand the statement of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I edited it again. I was confusing \bigcup and \bigcap while playing MathJax. On my handwritten paper, it's not like the unedited version before.

Answer (score 6):

Route to go:

First show that $P\left(1\right)$ **and** $P\left(2\right)$are
both true.

Setting $B:=A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{k}$ by applying $P\left(2\right)$
we find:

$\tag1 N\left(A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{k}\cup A_{k+1}\right)=N\left(B\cup A_{k+1}\right)=N\left(B\right)+N\left(A_{k+1}\right)-N\left(B\cap A_{k+1}\right)$

Under assumption that $P(k)$ is true find expressions for:  $$N\left(B\right)=N\left(A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{k}\right)$$
and for $$N\left(B\cap A_{k+1}\right)=N\left(\left(A_{1}\cap A_{k+1}\right)\cup\cdots\cup\left(A_{k}\cap A_{k+1}\right)\right)$$

Substitute these expressions in (1).

---

**edit**:

$N\left(B\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\right)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\right)+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+1}N\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\right)$

$N\left(B\cap A_{k+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{k+1}\right)-\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+1}N\left(\left(A_{1}\cap A_{k+1}\right)\cap\cdots\cap\left(A_{k}\cap A_{k+1}\right)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{k+1}\right)-\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+1}N\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\cap A_{k+1}\right)$

Substitution of this in the (1) gives the following RHS:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\right)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\right)+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+1}N\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\right)+N\left(A_{k+1}\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{k+1}\right)+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+2}N\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\cap A_{k+1}\right)$

After a rearrangement of the terms we find:

$N\left(A_{1}\cup\cdots\cup A_{k}\cup A_{k+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}N\left(A_{i}\right)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k+1}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\right)+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+2}N\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\cap A_{k+1}\right)$

wich is exactly statement $P\left(k+1\right)$.

Comment: $B:=A$ is commonly used by the introduction/definition of set $B$. If $B$ and $A$ have been introduced/defined already then $B=A$ is an equality that might be observed.

Comment: I guess ":=" is mentioned in more advanced logic or set theory books. Then is it okay to understand "B := A" mean "Define B as A"?

Comment: Yes, that is the right understanding in this context.

Comment: I've done a proof process for P(1) and P(2), but as for the P(2), it became "$N(A_1\bigcup A_2) = [N(A1)+N(A2)]−2N(A1∪A2)$", not $N(A_1\bigcup A_2) = [N(A1)+N(A2)]−N(A1∪A2)$. So it happened to prove P(2) is not true. I'm not sure whether it's the author's fault on giving a wrong equestion with $\cdots$ or my fault of reading the given equation wrong.

Comment: $N(A\cup B)=N((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B))=N(A\setminus B)+N(B\setminus A)+N(A\cap B)$. This because the $3$ sets are disjoint. RHS equals $N(A)+N(B)-N(A\cap B)$. On the left $\cup$ and on the right $\cap$. You did that wrong (again) in your comment.

Comment: No we have to use the equation shown in the book. The question is asking to prove the equation 

$N(A_1\cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = \sum\limits_{1\le i\le n} N(A_i) - \sum \limits_{1\le i<j \le n}N(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum \limits_{1\le i<j <k \le n}N(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - ...+(-1)^n+1 N(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n)$, which is a property P(n).

Comment: You commented: "...but for P(2) it became..." and clearly you messed up. I showed you in response how to prove P(2) correctly. Of course you must prove P(n) but that was not the issue of my comment. As shown in my answer you must start with proving P(1) *and* P(2). After that P(n) can be proved inductively.

Comment: You introduced a new equation on the RHS without a justification.In the picture added on the very top of my question, your euqation is not shown.

$$\text {As for P(2), using the given equation} $$   
$N(A_1\cup A_2) = \sum \limits_{1\le i \le 2}N(A_i) - \sum \limits_{1\le i <j \le 2} N(A_i \bigcap A_j) + \sum \limits_{1\le i <j<k \le 2} N(A_i \bigcap A_j \bigcap A_k) - \cdots + (-1)^{3} N(A_1\bigcap A_2)$    
$= [N(A_1)+N(A_2)] - N(A_1\cup A_2) + 0 - N (A_1\cup A_2)$ since $A_k=\emptyset$     
$= [N(A_1)+N(A_2)] - 2N(A_1\cup A_2$) 
I was trying to find my fault in the above process.

Comment: P(2) must be proved *on its own* (Theorem 9.3.3.) and *not* by applying the equation. This because the equation has not been proved yet. Then you cannot use it.

Comment: A cause of your confusion could be the factor $(-1)^{n+1}$. It might make you think that for e.g. P(2) you are dealing with more that $2$ summations. It is better to change the factor into $(-1)^{n-1}$. $P\left(2\right)$ is the statement that $N\left(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\right)=\sum_{1\leq i\leq2}N\left(A_{i}\right)-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\right)=N\left(A_{1}\right)+N\left(A_{2}\right)-N\left(A_{1}\cap A_{2}\right)$.
Compare this with your result in order to find your fault in the proces.

Comment: You seem to be confusing something. I tried substituting terms to set B as you suggested. $\color {red}{But\space N(B) + N(A_{k+1}) = N(A_1\cup A_2\cdots\cup A_k) + N(A_{k+1}), not\space \sum \limits_{1\le i \le k+1} N(A_i)}, \text {which should be in the result to complete the proof}$

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: I read it, but i think the proof is not clear. I edited whole part of my attempt to prove the theorem again.

Comment: What is unclear about it?

Comment: How do you jump from 

$N(B)=∑_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\right)-∑_{1≤i<j≤ k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\right)+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+1}N\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k}\right)$

to  

$N(B∩A_{k+1})=∑_{i=1}^{k}N\left(A_{i}\cap A_{k+1}\right)-\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{k+1}N\left(\left(A_{1} ∩ A_{k+1}\right)\cap\cdots ∩ \left(A_{k} ∩ A_{k+1}\right)\right)$                                                                                                                      ?

Comment: It is no jump in the sense that the statement about $N(B\cap A_{k+1})$ should be a consequence of the statement about $N(B)$. In both (separate) cases the equalities arise by application of $P(k)$. As I said in the first part of the proof: "under assumption that $P(k)$ is true find expressions for:..." It concerns two different cases. No jump from one case to another.

Comment: I discovered this proof earlier today. I'm now debating if the induction or the counting proof is more clear. I applaud your patience +1

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thank you for upvote and compliment. Also let me attend you on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3408241/75923). It provides a more general (and IMV more elegant) proof of PIE and avoids induction. It is based on indicator functions. Further it reveals that the essential root of PIE is actually the fact that for every non-empty finite set the number of subsets that have even cardinality is the same as the number of subsets that have odd cardinality.

Comment: @drhab: is the term $(-1)^{k+1}N(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{k})$ absorbed into " $+ \cdots +$" for the statement $P(k+1)$?

Comment: @K.M Yes, it is.