# How is this combinatorial relation called?

Tags: combinatorics

I was trying to learn some set theory and came up with the following relation between the union and intersection:

For any set consisting of sets $A$, we have:
$$\left\vert\bigcup_{a\in A}a\right\vert=\sum_{i=1}^{|A|}\bigg((-1)^{i+1}\sum_{B\subseteq A, |B|=i}\left\vert\bigcap_{b\in B}b\right\vert\bigg)$$
To me this is pretty obvious. We take the sum of all the cardinalities and then subtract those that were added twice. We then add the ones that were substracted twice back in et cetera.

The thing is, I have no idea how one would prove this (induction maybe?) or whether it's already proven and has some sort of name.

Is there anyone who can help me to either prove/disprove this relation or, if it already exists, give its name?

Comment: This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Thank you. Would you please consider putting this into an answer that I can then accept?

Comment: Not every thing revolving sets is of set theoretic interest. If the question, or relation, or whatever, revolves around "how many" it is more likely to be about combinatorics, than it is about set theory.

Comment: I am not really sure link-only answers are allowed, I don't provide any insight by posting this Wikipedia page.

Comment: @C.Falcon Yes, you do. I agree with the OP,  your comment should be the accepted answer

Comment: For a proof of the principle have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1674481/75923). It is a proof indeed based on induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Note to reviewers: added as an answer at request of OP.