# Passengers probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a train with $m$ wagons and $n$ $(n\geq m)$ passengers. Calculate the probability where for every wagon there is at least one passenger to enter.

Let $A$ be "there is a passenger on every wagon", $A_k$ be "there is a(t least one) passenger on the $k$-th wagon".

If we want $A$ to be realized, every $A_k$ have to realize: $A = \bigcap_{k=1}^{m} A_k.$

De Morgan's laws: $\overline{A}= \bigcup_{k=1}^{m} \overline{A_k}$, where $\overline{A_k}$ is "there are no passengers on the $k$-th wagon".

After this step I couldn't follow my probability teacher so if anyone could explain it to me, I would be very very grateful:

$P(\overline{A_i}) =\frac{(m-1)^n}{m^n}$, $P(\overline{A_i}\overline{A_j}) = \frac{(m-2)^n}{m^n}$ etc. After this we could conclude that in every wagon can be $n$ passengers, but I don't think it's the case. What does it actually mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with inlcusion-exclusion formuale?

The probability that none of $A_\alpha$ occurs (for $k$ distinct indices $\alpha$) is that every passenger selected, independently, any of the $m - k$ other wagons; hence, it is $\dfrac{(m - k)^n}{m^n}.$

Comment: yes I am, this was just one step before use of the formula. I am sorry I don't understand, can you be more specific, for example can you explain the idea of $P(\overline{A_i})$?

Comment: Ok, everyone of the $n$ passengers need to choose a wagon, and the event where $A_i$ does not occur mean that each one of the passengers chose a wagon that was not the $i$th one, hence, they could have chosen uniformly at random any of the other $m-1$ wagons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose 1 bin that is empty and allocate all passengers to the remaining $m-1$. Repaeat $m-1$ times. This comes up to $\binom{m}{1} (m-1)^n$ times. For each such allocation you have over counted any two bins, so need to subtract $\binom{m}{2}( m-2)^n$. Now you have over counted three bins, need to add them back. And so on. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

> "After this step I couldn't follow my probability teacher so if anyone could explain it to me..."

I grasp your question as an opportunity to explain the principle of [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). This also to have an answer that I can use eventually as a reference by answering later questions. Often I see proofs of PIE that use induction and are connected with a specific measure and I regret that. This because PIE has a nice base in indicator functions and is surprisingly easy to prove in that context. Only at one spot induction is very welcome, which is the (omitted) proof that for a non-empty finite set the number of subsets with even cardinality equals the number of subsets with odd cardinality.

You can make use of corollary 2 by taking $P$ for $\mu$ and $A_i^{\complement}$ for $B_i$.

---

**Theorem**:

Let $I$ be a finite set and for every $i\in I$ let $B_{i}\subseteq\Omega$.

Then: $$\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{i}}+\sum_{\varnothing\neq K\subseteq I\wedge\left|K\right|\text{even}}\mathbf{1}_{\bigcap_{i\in K}B_{i}}=\sum_{K\subseteq I\wedge\left|K\right|\text{odd}}\mathbf{1}_{\bigcap_{i\in K}B_{i}}$$

**Proof of theorem**:

Fix some $\omega\in\Omega$ and let $I\left(\omega\right):=\left\{ i\in I\mid\omega\in B_{i}\right\} $.

If $I\left(\omega\right)=\varnothing$ then substitution of $\omega$
on both sides leads to: $$0+0=0$$ which is evidently a true statement.

If $I\left(\omega\right)\neq\varnothing$ then $\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{i}}\left(\omega\right)=1$.

Secondly it is not difficult to prove that: $$\left|\left\{ K\subseteq I\left(\omega\right):\left|K\right|\text{ is even}\right\} \right|=2^{\left|I\left(\omega\right)\right|-1}=\left|\left\{ K\subseteq I\left(\omega\right):\left|K\right|\text{ is odd}\right\} \right|$$
Concerning even cardinality we only take into account the subsets
that are *not empty* so substitution of $\omega$ on both sides leads
to: $$1+\left(2^{\left|I\left(\omega\right)\right|-1}-1\right)=2^{\left|I\left(\omega\right)\right|-1}$$
which again is evidently a true statement.

This completes the proof.

---

**Corollary 1**:

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$be a measure space, let
$I$ be a finite set and for every $i\in I$ let $B_{i}\in\mathcal{A}$.

Then: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{i}\right)+\sum_{\varnothing\neq K\subseteq I\wedge\left|K\right|\text{even}}\mu\left(\bigcap_{i\in K}B_{i}\right)=\sum_{K\subseteq I\wedge\left|K\right|\text{odd}}\mu\left(\bigcap_{i\in K}B_{i}\right)$$

**Proof of corollary 1**:

Apply the theorem and afterward take the integral wrt to $\mu$ on both sides.

---

**Corollary 2** (application of symmetry):

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu\right)$be a measure space, let
$I=\left\{ 1,2,\dots,n\right\} $ be a finite set and for every $i\in I$
let $B_{i}\in\mathcal{A}$.

Moreover let it be that $\mu\left(\bigcap_{i\in K}B_{i}\right)$
only depends on the cardinality of $K$.

Then: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{i}\right)+\sum_{1\leq m\leq\lfloor\frac{1}{2}n\rfloor}\binom{n}{2m}\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2m}B_{i}\right)=\sum_{1\leq m\leq\lceil\frac{1}{2}n\rceil}\binom{n}{2m-1}\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2m-1}B_{i}\right)$$

**Proof of corollary 2**:

Straightforward.

---