# On notation of the generalized probability union formula

Tags: probability, proof-writing, notation

Let $(A_i)$ be a finite family of events of a probability space. Then

$$P(\bigcup A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m P(A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^m P(A_i \cap A_j) + ... +(-1)^{m-1} P(A_1 \cap ... \cap A_m)$$

This theorem is pretty intuitive. However the way it's stated is not very elegant. Is there a better way to notate this? Intuitively very sum will be over the probabilities of the intersections of a finite number of events modulo commutativity, but trying to express that seems even more complicated than the current formula.

The writter also has difficulty proving this theorem. Even though the general process is intuitive, trying to write it out rapidily gets stuck in a wall of notation. Are there any tips on how to write proofs for these notation-heavy (but not deep) theorems without getting lost in messy notation?

Comment: Look for "inclusion-exclusion principle" for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle  See some ways it is written there.

Comment: @OP For any probability function $P(.)$ the proof can be done by using the axioms of probability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms). First, prove it for $m=2$, and then proceed by induction.

Comment: The proof can be done by induction but IMV it is much better to look at the underlying indicator functions. Actually it rests on nothing more than the fact that for a non-empty finite set the number of subsets with even cardinality equals the number of subsets with odd cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that using indicator functions for a finite index set $I$ we have:$$\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}}=\sum_{\varnothing\neq J\subseteq I}(-1)^{|J|-1}\mathbf{1}_{\bigcap_{i\in J}A_{i}}$$

See the proof of the theorem stated in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3408241/75923).

Taking expectations with respect to probability measure $P$ on both side we arrive at:$$P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)=\sum_{\varnothing\neq J\subseteq I}(-1)^{|J|-1}P\left(\bigcap_{i\in J}A_{i}\right)$$That is the same expression in your answer for $I=\{1,\dots,m\}$.